# Rails order by association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, psql

My goal is to sort the posts by Total amount of votes. As you can see in the controller, at first I sorted the posts by created_at, which worked! However I wanted to change it so it would be sorted by total votes. The votes come from the acts_as_votable gem. Which is associated with Post

Currently this is my posts controller:

```
    def index
        # @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC") <--This works
        @posts = Post.includes(:votes).order("votes_for.size desc")
    end
```

When I run this I get the following error:Association named 'votes' was not found on Post; perhaps you misspelled it?

My guess is that includes does not work here.

When I open up rails console. To test the association I get the following:

```
@post = Post.first
@post.votes_for.size
```

It shows that I currently have 2 votes.

Lastly here is my Post.rb Model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_votable
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "700x500>#", small: "350x250>" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Thanks in advance!!!
(I am using psql)

Add Schema:

```
 create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "link"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "name"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

  create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "votable_id"
    t.string   "votable_type"
    t.integer  "voter_id"
    t.string   "voter_type"
    t.boolean  "vote_flag"
    t.string   "vote_scope"
    t.integer  "vote_weight"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "votes", ["votable_id", "votable_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_votable_id_and_votable_type_and_vote_scope", using: :btree
  add_index "votes", ["voter_id", "voter_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_voter_id_and_voter_type_and_vote_scope", using: :btree

  add_foreign_key "comments", "posts"
  add_foreign_key "comments", "users"
end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789255/rails-4-acts-as-votable-change-default-sort-order

Comment: Is votes_for column of `Post` or `Vote` ? If its part of 'Vote' how you able to do `@post.votes_for.size` ?

Comment: Can you include your schema.rb?

Comment: I just added the schema.rb

Comment: Thanks @Athar that was very useful and I was able to fix my problem!!!